# Entity Framework: Invalid column name 'OrganizationStructure_ID'

Tags: entity-framework

I get : ERROR: Invalid column name 'OrganizationStructure_ID'.

```
    public OrganizationStructure()
    {
        ChildrenItems = new HashSet<OrganizationStructure>();
        InputDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationTypeID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationActivityID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationLocationID { get; set; }

    public string AddRemark { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InputDate { get; set; }
    public int? RemAttr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationStructure> ChildrenItems { get; set; }
```

INDEX ACTION:

```
    return View(_organizationStructureRepository.GetAll().ToList() 
             .Where(t => t.ParentID == null));
```

Comment: is `OrganizationStructure` an entity (from EF?) What's the exception you get?

Comment: EF, Exception: Invalid column name 'OrganizationStructure_ID'

Comment: apparenty the automatic foreign key named changed from {entity}ID to {entity}_ID at some point. EF5 maybe.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is because you didn't pair your FK property with a navigation property. I expect the `ParentID` should point to parent `OrganizationStructure` and `ChildrenItems` should point to children `OranizationStructures`.

If your model doesn't contain `Parent` navigation property to parent `OrganizationStructure` you must use fluent-API to tell EF that `ParentID` is FK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationStructure>()
            .HasMany(o => o.ChildrenItems)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
```

Comment: @boomhauer: Override `OnModelCreating` method in your derived `DbContext` class and put all mappings there. Another option is to use `EntityTypeConfiguration` derived class and register it in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: i foudn how to add a foreignkey attibute to the model that took care of this for me though. but thanks

Comment: @boomhauer, What foreign key attribute did you put where?

Comment: Is there any way to turn the magic off. I have a Map file with a HasForeignKey yet still get this error.  I would of thought having a specific Map file disables convention wireup?

Comment: It's also could be if you declare reference field in child entity as simple field, but not a property!
int ParentId - will be ignored;
int ParentId {get; set;} - it'ok (but could be ignored if the parent entity name isn't 'Parent');
[ForeignKey("MyParentEntity")]
int ParentId {get; set;} - the best way (or use fluent-api)

Answer (score 7):

What I have figured out is when you have an ICollection that references a table and there is no column that it can figure out, it creates one for you to try to make the connection between the tables.  This specifically happens with ICollection and has driven me "batty" trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, removing unwanted entry of public virtual ICollection, solved it.

Comment: Same here, this killed me until I found this

Answer (score 3):

It's also could be if you declare reference field in child entity as simple field, but not a property!

```
int ParentId  //will be ignored; 

int ParentId {get; set;} // it'ok (but could be ignored 
                         //if the parent entity name isn't 'Parent'); 

[ForeignKey("MyParentEntity")] 
int ParentId {get; set;} // is the best way (or use fluent-api)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a test project, make sure the connection strings are updated for test project

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the project to newer version of .Net Framework, so I suppose there was a conflict with the Entity Framework libraries, uninstall/install Entity Framework worked for me

```
uninstall-package entityframework
install-package entityframework
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to SQL server Management -> Tools -> Sql Server Profiler.

Start a profiler. Using the eraser, clean all events.
Send the request using Postman, or just call your Queryable in order to execute the Sql Command.

Copy the generated query from the profiler and paste in SQL server Management (You have to do minor changes in order to convert this string in a SQL statement, moving parameters from the end to variables)
Execute the  query and You will see which table needs this column.