# Invalid column name in EF

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a situation where EF is trying to get a field value from the table "VideoClip" that I didn't ask it to get.

[image: Database schema showing the tables NewsItemVideoClip, NewsItem, VideoClip and Video]

The complete generated query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[NewsItemId] AS [NewsItemId], 
[Project1].[VideoClipId] AS [VideoClipId], 
[Project1].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
[Project1].[Video_Id] AS [Video_Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[NewsItemId] AS [NewsItemId], 
    [Extent1].[VideoClipId] AS [VideoClipId], 
    [Extent1].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
    [Extent1].[Video_Id] AS [Video_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[NewsItemVideoClip] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[NewsItemId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[DisplayOrder] DESC
```

However, my `NewsItemVideoClip` entity class looks like this:

```
public class NewsItemVideoClip : Entity
{
    public virtual int NewsItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual int VideoClipId { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsItem NewsItem { get; set; }
    public virtual VideoClip VideoClip { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping:

```
public class NewsItemVideoClipEntityMapping
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<NewsItemVideoClip>
{
    public NewsItemVideoClipEntityMapping()
    {
        //configure key and properties
        HasKey(c => c.Id);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.NewsItem)
            .WithMany(x => x.NewsItemVideoClips)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.NewsItemId);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.VideoClip)
            .WithMany(x => x.NewsItemVideos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.VideoClipId);

        //configure table map
        ToTable("NewsItemVideoClip");
    }
}
```

The LINQ query:

```
public IList<NewsItemVideoClip> GetVideoClips(int newsItemId)
{
    var query = from nvc in _newsItemVideoClipRepository.GetAll()
                where nvc.NewsItemId == newsItemId
                orderby nvc.DisplayOrder descending
                select nvc;

    var newsItemVideoClips = query.ToList();
    return newsItemVideoClips;
}
```

Howcome EF gives me: `Invalid column name 'Video_Id'`?

Comment: Can you please post your LINQ query?

Comment: Video_Id would be a foreign key it is expecting to the Video table.  Check your Video modal class and fluent mapping to see if it has a many/collection reference to NewsItemVideoClip.

Comment: Omg! What i did that for? )))

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997562/entity-framework-invalid-column-name-organizationstructure-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your diagram, VideoClip has a VideoId which I guess is your intended foreign key to Video.  Video_Id would be the default foreignkey name for the foreign key in the abscence of mapping that would name it otherwise.  So probably need a `.HasForeignKey(x => x.VideoId);` to your **VideoClip** mapping.