# Entity Framework Fluent API Mapping Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

How can I configure relationships between three tables to get all related data?

I have the following models (and the same tables in database):

```
public class Client 
{
  public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public virtual ClientCard ClientCard { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
  public Guid CardId { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual ClientCard ClientCard { get; set; }
}

public class ClientCard
{
  public Guid ClientCardId { get; set; }
  public Guid CardId { get; set; }
  public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
  public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

And the following OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        ...

        builder.Entity<ClientCard>()
            .HasKey(x => x.ClientCardId);

        builder.Entity<ClientCard>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Client)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.ClientCard);

        builder.Entity<ClientCard>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Card)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.ClientCard);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

But the results return without related data. Why?

Comment: Why do you have 2 Card classes?

Comment: Actually, I have something like Users and Roles in Asp.Net: Client as Users, Card as Roles, ClientCard as UserInRoles

Comment: But you have 2 classes with the same name, at least thats what you're showing us in your code

Comment: Are you going to use foreign keys in your database for these tables?

Comment: @code I think that the third class should have a name `ClientCard`

Comment: How are you fetching the data?

Comment: I still think if your model looks like that could be a problem... `code`

Comment: I recommend to create a separate map-file for each entities.

Answer (score 0):

For your code please try something like:

```
public class Client 
{
  public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<ClientCard> ClientCard { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
  public Guid CardId { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<ClientCard> ClientCard { get; set; }
}

public class ClientCard
{
  public Guid ClientCardId { get; set; }
  public Guid CardId { get; set; }
  public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
  public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

And mapping:

```
    builder.Entity<Client>()
           .HasKey(t => t.ClinetID);
    ....
    builder.Entity<Client>()
           .HasMany(a => a.ClientCard)
           .WithRequired(p => p.Client)
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.ClientID);
```

For Card

```
    ....
    builder.Entity<Card>()
           .HasMany(a => a.ClientCard)
           .WithRequired(p => p.Card)
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.CardID);
```

But I think the best way is to create a separate map-file for each entities

Comment: Thank you @MegaTron. Your solution helped me partially, but i would like to have one-to-one relationship between ClientCard and Client, ClientCard and Card.

In other words, there are lots of clients and cards, but only one client can exist with one card only. Cannot add the same client with few different cards in ClientCard table OR cannot add few different clients with the same card in CLientCard table.

Comment: Or maybe, has a solution to add zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship between Client and Card, so it will let to get rid of the ClientCard table?

Comment: How are you fetching the data?

Comment: _context.Set<Client>().ToList() and _context.Set<Card>().ToList()

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using the following models:

```
public class Client 
{
   public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public Guid? CardId { get; set; }
   public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
   public Guid CardId { get; set; }
   public string Number { get; set; }

   //public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

and the following OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        ... 

        builder.Entity<Client>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Card)
            //.WithOptionalPrincipal(x=> x.Client) 
            //or
            //.WithOptionalDependent(x=> x.Client)
            ;

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

All clients return with related data(if exists). But if I want to get ralated data with Card object and uncomment `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }` and WithOptionalPrincipal/WithOptionalDependent I always get on of these SqlException: "invalid column name 'Client_ClientId'" (if WithOptionalPrincipal is used) OR "invalid column name 'Card_CardId'" (if WithOptionalDependent is used)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts

Comment: That is because you didn't pair your FK property with a navigation property. [A similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8997562/4275342)

Comment: Try to add `.Map(t => t.MapKey("ClientID"));`

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help

Comment: _context.Set<Client>().ToList() and _context.Set<Card>().ToList()

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for my case.

First, I have removed CardId from Client class.
Second, I have changed my OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        ...

        builder.Entity<Client>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Card)
            .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Client)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("CardId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        builder.Entity<Card>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Client)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Card)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```