# No process is on the other end of pipe while connecting to SQL Server in an ASP.NET Core application via EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I can log in into SQL Server 2017 from SSMS with a SQL Server login. But when I'm debugging my Web API project, using EF Core, I get an exception

> No process is on other end of pipe

The connection string is as below

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "InventoryConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=InventoryDB;user=aXXXXX;password=XXXXX"
}
```

I checked the SQL Server configuration manager and enabled TCP/IP and NamedPipes and SharedMemory and the protocol order list is SharedMemeory 1, TCP/IP 2 and Named Pipes 3. I tried all the solutions given at [pinal dev](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) But still the error persists.

I restarted the service, restarted my PC - but nothing works. Am I missing anything far out?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'User Id' instead of 'user' in your connection string.

Could you check this connection string?

```
Server=.;Database=InventoryDB;User Id=aXXXXX;Password=XXXXX;
```

For more information you can check this site:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

The error was because there was no database with the name that I specified in the connection string. I was expecting `EF Core` to create a new database. But turns out I was wrong.
I'm really mistaken at how `EF Core` differs from `EF 6.x` in terms of initial database creation. After posting the question, I stumbled on the point to create EF migrations to create a new database. I wondered aren't there other way to create an initial database when the application is first run(that's how EF 6.x supported). I came to know that `Context.Database.EnsureCreated()` achieves the same.

Comment: Many of my answers concerning EF Core here on SO contain simple and fully working console projects that create a database on the fly. Here is a [random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62861267/2618319) of mine that does that.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying out a new console app with EF Core 5.0, and was hitting some errors similar to the above. Brand new DB entry in my LocalDB - and I had not installed the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools yet. Once I did that and did the Powershell NuGet Console commands

Add-Migration Init

Update-Database

The commands worked - and my connection was working as it was expected to do. I just had not remembered to do that - and that was my root cause.